# group items with class A preceded by an element with class B

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to group the li tags with the class "sub" into a container () only if they have an element before them that contains the class "title". I was able wrap all the consecutive elements with "sub" into a "container" but still the first groups of subs needs to be disregarded as they don't have a "title" class before them.

```js
$('.sub').not('.sub+.sub').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(.sub)').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
  </ul>
```

Is there a way to group only the items that are preceded by an element with the class "title" ? also considering that there could be multiple UL's like the one in the example

Comment: What about `$('.title + .sub').each(/* ... */)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find by the title
2. Find all the elements after the title until, not including, the next title
3. Wrap them all with the container div

```js
$('.title').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.title').wrapAll('<div class="container">');
});
```

```css
.container { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
    <li class="sub">...</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: this did it thanks a lot, so .nextUntil('.title') will wrap all items until but not including the next title?

Comment: @MarioPerez The `wrapAll` is the part that makes it wrap all of them in a single tag, where as `wrap` would put each one in its own tag.  `nextUntil` is just the selection part of finding all proceeding siblings, until it finds one it should not include, and then stops.